# navbar height (or padding) in jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to figure out how to change the height of list items in a jquery mobile navbar. I've looked through all the css and tried changing everything I've found but nothing has worked so far. Hope someone can help!

Here's the code:

```
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" style="background: url('../images/stripe.gif') repeat top left;">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul class="custom-navbar">
                    <li><a href="#sun">Sun</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mon">Mon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tue">Tue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#wed">Wed</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#thu">Thu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fri">Fri</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sat">Sat</a></li>
                </ul>
```

[Here's a link to see how it's rendering.](http://www.triadbarspecials.com/app) The 7 items at the top (the days of the week), as you can see have lots of space above and below them inside their borders. I want much less space there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                    <ul class="custom-navbar ui-grid-f">
                        <li class="ui-block-a"><a href="#sun" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Sun</span></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-block-b" style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#mon" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Mon</span></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-block-c" style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#tue" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Tue</span></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-block-d" style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#wed" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Wed</span></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-block-e" style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#thu" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Thu</span></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-block-c ui-block-f" style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#fri" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Fri</span></span></a></li>
                        <li class="ui-block-g" style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#sat" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Sat</span></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

There is your initialized grid. You can see that I added `padding-left: -5px` to all but the first `<li>` element to take away the space between them. I would either use a class to add the `margin` to the elements or if you are targeting browsers that support CSS3 then you can use the `:nth-child()` selector to get all but the first `<li>` element.

### Update

Here is how to change your code so that it will look like the above code after jQuery Mobile initializes it:

```
            <ul class="custom-navbar">
                <li><a href="#sun">Sun</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#mon">Mon</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#tue">Tue</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#wed">Wed</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#thu">Thu</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#fri">Fri</a></li>
                <li style="margin-left: -5px;"><a href="#sat">Sat</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jasper. This definitely works on the list that you got that code from, but what I'm looking for is to change the padding in a different list - the navigation list at the top of the page (and in the code that I posted in my question).

Comment: That still didn't get it. I tried pasting the code directly in place of what I have (which isn't initialized) and it doubled the margins. Also tried, with my code, give each initialized class a padding and margin of 0, and that didn't work.    Seems like the padding is set to an EM of some value because when I change the font size, the padding amount changes as well.

Comment: @JustinWhite Check-out the **update** to my answer. Just just need to add the padding to the `<li>` elements.

Comment: Actually, I finally found the CSS, after changing the value of every instance of padding in the CSS document. Here's the CSS that I added to my page:     `.ui-header .ui-btn-inner,  
  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-top .ui-btn-inner,  
  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-right .ui-btn-inner,  
  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-bottom .ui-btn-inner,  
  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-left .ui-btn-inner { padding: 0px !important; }`